# iTextSharp STRIKETHRU is not working correctly. STRIKETHRU the whole text

Tags: c#, itext

I'm trying to archive a text with a STRIKETHRU fragment
I tried this approach and cannot figure out why it's not working

desired output: blabla <s>123</s> blabla

what I get: <s>blabla 123 blabla</s>

My tech stack is .net

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

//.........

var t1 = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 20, Font.DEFAULTSIZE);
            var t2 = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 10, Font.STRIKETHRU);

            var p1 = new Phrase("0123456789", t1);
            var p2 = new Phrase("0123456789", t2);
            var p3 = new Phrase("0123456789", t1);
            var p4 = new Phrase("0123456789", t1);

            p1.AddSpecial(p2);
            p1.AddSpecial(p3);

            PdfPTable datatable1 = new PdfPTable(1);
            datatable1.TotalWidth = 700f;
            datatable1.LockedWidth = false;
            datatable1.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

            datatable1.AddCell(" ");
            datatable1.AddCell(p1);
            datatable1.AddCell(" ");
            datatable1.AddCell(p1);
            datatable1.AddCell(" ");
            datatable1.AddCell(p2);
            datatable1.AddCell(" ");
            datatable1.AddCell(p3);
            datatable1.AddCell(" ");
            datatable1.AddCell(p4);
            datatable1.AddCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("123", t1)));
            datatable1.AddCell(new Phrase(new Chunk("123", t2)));
```

I also tried with  p1.Add(p2); with the same result

[image]

Comment: which version [tag:itext] you are using?

Comment: iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core 3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

the answer is this

```
var p1 = Phrase.GetInstance("blabla ");
p1.Font = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 20, Font.DEFAULTSIZE);


var p2 = Phrase.GetInstance("123");
p2.Font = new Font(Font.HELVETICA, 20, Font.STRIKETHRU);
```

gives the result: blabla <s>123</s>

Answer (score 0):

With these below changes, the generated PDF should have the desired strikethrough effect on the appropriate text.

```
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("output.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Create))
{
    var doc = new Document();
    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, stream);
    doc.Open();

    var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
    var normalFont = new Font(baseFont, 12);
    var strikethroughFont = new Font(baseFont, 12);
    strikethroughFont.SetStyle(Font.STRIKETHRU);

    var p1 = new Phrase("0123456789", normalFont);
    var p2 = new Phrase("AAAAAAAAAA", strikethroughFont);
    var p3 = new Phrase("BBBBBBBBBB", normalFont);
    var p4 = new Phrase("CCCCCCCCCC", strikethroughFont);

    PdfPTable datatable1 = new PdfPTable(1);
    datatable1.TotalWidth = 700f;
    datatable1.LockedWidth = false;
    datatable1.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;

    datatable1.AddCell(" ");
    datatable1.AddCell(p1);
    datatable1.AddCell(" ");
    datatable1.AddCell(p2);
    datatable1.AddCell(" ");
    datatable1.AddCell(p3);
    datatable1.AddCell(" ");
    datatable1.AddCell(p4);

    doc.Add(datatable1);
    doc.Close();
}
```